# How do I only write to a file once every round in my game?

Tags: java, file

### Background

I want to write to a file that would contain the high scores in my game.

### Issue

Every time `tick()` gets called the program writes to the file with the score, however, I only want it to write the score once every time the game ends.

For example, if my score was `30`, it would print `30` 5 times if I leave the window open for `5ms`

*How do I get my program to only write once and not every `100ms`?*

### Code

Game loop:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    while (isRunning)
    {
        tick();
        //render(); Not important in terms of this question

        try
        {
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    stop();
}
```

`tick()` gets called once every `100ms`.

```
private void tick() 
{
     //inGame is just a global variable to determine if still in game
     //move() is a method used to move the player object.
     if (inGame) move();
     else Util.writeScore("scores", 10); 
     //10 is just an example, score would be held in a variable in production.
}

private void writeScore(String fileName, int score)
{
    if (score == 0) 
        return;
    else 
    {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
        {
            out.println(score);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by implementing code that makes sure you don't write to it more than once. I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: @Stultuske lol I know that, but how do I do that?

Comment: Why not include `Util.writeScore()` in your `stop()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two flags -- like this:

```
  // Globals
  int inGame=1; // 1 when in game 0 when not
  int scoreDone=0;  // 1 when score written 0 when not.

private void tick() 
{
   //inGame is just a global variable to determine if still in game
   //move() is a method used to move the player object.
   if (inGame == 1) 
     move();
   if ((inGame == 0) && (scoreDone == 0))
   {
     Util.writeScore("scores", 10);
     scoreDone = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this C syntax? I don't think ints are implicitly considered as booleans by Java.